# How to programmatically change the FontColor of a Tlabel

Tags: delphi, colors, label, delphi-xe5, firemonkey-fm3

When I put a `TLabel` on a form, I can change the color of its text by changing the `FontColor` property. However, when I do this in my program by

```
Label1.FontColor := TAlphaColors.Aquamarine;
```

this doesn't work. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: FireMonkey is not like that at all. You need to learn about styles. Start with the program docs.

Comment: That does not explain why I can change the font color by manually setting a property and not by doing the same in my program.

Comment: You need to exclude the [`ssFontColor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Graphics.ITextSettings.StyledSettings) style from the label's [`style set`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Controls.TTextControl.StyledSettings), otherwise the font color from the assigned style will be applied to the label. (if it uses the same logic as in Delphi XE3)

Comment: @TLama - ssFontColor was already excluded but ssStyle did the trick. If you make that an answer I'll accept it as thanks for showing me this suggestion, that led me to the correct solution.

Comment: It does indeed explain that. Did you find the documentation?

Comment: @David - of course: "Embarcadero Technologies does not currently have any additional information. Please help us document this topic by using the Discussion page"

Comment: You must be looking at different pages. TLama's links, and the pages I found were clear. Docs for fmx are a bit sketchy though I agree

Comment: @Arnold, I would rather let this answer someone experienced or at least someone who has Delphi XE5. I'll be silently waiting at least 1 or 2 years before I start to think to write something serious on FMX :-)

Comment: I was jumping to conclusions a bit too fast. To programmatically change the `FontColor` the following works: `FText.StyledSettings := FText.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.ssFontColor]; FText.FontColor := TAlphaColors.Cyan;` (where FText is a `TLabel`). The docs with the dreaded Embarcadero lack of effort in documentation was about `FontColor`. TLama's answer and link were the correct one. Thanks to both TLama and David for their help and persistence ;-)

Answer (score 9):

To enable modifying font color of a `TLabel` object, you need to change its `StyledSettings` property.

It's an array defining the different settings that are defined by the current style and cannot be changed by other means.

To be able to change the color of the font, you have to remove the `TStyledSetting.FontColor` entry from this array.

You can do it programmatically with

```
Label1.StyledSettings := Label1.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.FontColor];
```

or from the Object Inspector in the designer, select your label, go in `StyledSettings` and untick `FontColor`.

Other settings that can be fixed by the current style are

- `TStyledSetting.Family`
- `TStyledSetting.Size`
- `TStyledSetting.Style`
- `TStyledSetting.Other`

So, for being able to change the font color and the size, you would write:

```
Label1.StyledSettings := Label1.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.FontColor, TStyledSetting.Size];
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tried the answer from @NicolasDusart and found out, that a `TLabel` doesn't seem to have `StyledSettings`. I guess this changed in newer versions of Delphi, I'm currently using Delphi Tokyo. However with this I was able to change the font color:

```
Label1.StyleElements := Label1.StyleElements - [seFont];
```

The Delphi documentation lists `TStyleElements` as as set:

```
type TStyleElements = set of (seFont, seClient, seBorder);
```

[Vcl.Controls.TStyleElements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Controls.TStyleElements)

Comment: He refers to FMX, not VCL

Answer (score 1):

Sub a TLabel for  TText Control. problem solved !

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I ran into the same issue where the Color was not sticking for TLabels. Instead of a using a TLabel, use a TText Control. You can code something like - 'MyText.Color := TAlphaColors.Dodgerblue;'

Comment: Allows you to avoid style sheets and etc.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this solution, didn't know it. Anyhow, my problem with TLabel was solved by TLama and mentioned in my comment.

Answer (score -1):

We can change TLabel color programmatically as:

```
Label1.Font.Color := clBlue;
```

Comment: This is not Firemonkey, is it?